# function stops when fetch() fails

Tags: javascript

so I have a normal thing you would do to find if a file exists and proceed accordingly:

```
let response = await fetch(url);
if (response.ok) {
  //it exists
} else {
  //it doesn't
}
```

Problem is, of course, if it fails it gives me a `TypeError: Failed to fetch` and my function stops.
Is there a way I can suppress the error?
I cannot change from a fetch function, i've tried everything else and fetch is the best option in my context.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use try-catch: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp

Comment: @SeReGa I'd recommend using [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) over w3schools.

Comment: @SeReGa thank you very much, it works exactly like I wanted it to.

Comment: @Phix Can you explain why? w3schools looks more readable to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to implement `try and catch`  and it is quite easy to implement it. You can have a look at [Try and Catch Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp)

Have a look at the sample code below

```
try {
  let response = await fetch(url);
}
catch(err) {
  alert("Error Message : " + err.message);
}
```

Comment: You should handle the `err` from `catch(err)` value instead.

Comment: Yes, you are right and I already edited the sample code.

Comment: worked great! Just a side question, is there any way I can get rid of the other `GET` errors for console clutter reasons?

Comment: Just put a `console.clear();` and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can suppress the error?

You should wrap your function that may cause the error in `try...catch`.

```js
const fetch = (isFine) => new Promise(resolve => {
  if(isFine) 
    resolve("Normal data");
  else
    throw new Error("Error msg...!");
});

const myFunction = async (isFine) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(isFine);
    console.log(response);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Oops..." + err.message);
  }
}

myFunction(true);
myFunction(false);
```